# How do I ask a question about an existing answer?

Tags: support, asking-questions

How do I ask a question about an answer to a question someone else asked?

For example: *"Can this solution be extended to do blah blah?"*

Comment: With a comment.

Comment: Or ask a question as normal and reference the existing question and answer in that question. You'll need to make sure everything is self contained in your question and that you're clear how the existing answer doesn't answer your extended question.

Comment: @Aladdin the comment box hint literally says they're used to "ask for more information." If you were told not to do that, whoever told you was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a lot on the specifics of the question and answer.

For some, maybe you only need to post a comment to get some clarification or additional details.

For others, a you can post a new question; although it can be tricky:

- The new question need to be completely self-contained, and to have all the necessary details **within** the post.
- At the same time, it's best that you refer to the other Q&A pair and explain **how and why** that particular answer does not solve your requirements, to hopefully avoid other users closing your question as a duplicate for the first one.

You would have to do research on your own to properly document how the other answer doesn't have the necessary details to fulfill your requirements, and construct a question that can stand on its own legs without depending on the other Q&A.

It's not unlikely that you would arrive to your own solution while creating such a question. **If so, maybe you can contribute another answer with the extended details to the orginal question, or post a comment with the result of your research under the original answer**.

Again, the specifics of the case are very important.

It could even be the case that the best solution is to post a bounty on the original question, looking for new answers that better respond to your needs.